# Add a column that shows whether the two previous columns include 0 or not

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops, lapply

I have a data.frame called `dat`. I want to add a new column to it called `dif`. Then, in each row if `lower` and `upper` range included **0** (e.g., `-0.41`  to `0.1` in 1st row) I want the `dif` value to show `FALSE` else (e.g.,  `0.10` to   `0.2` 2nd row) `TRUE`.

Is this possible to do in R for any similar data.frame (*the following is a toy example a functional answer is appreciated*)?

```
dat <- data.frame(lower = c(-0.41, .1, -.2), upper = 1:3*.1, row.names = paste("a", 1:3)) # add a column called `dif`


desired_output <- data.frame(lower = c(-0.41, .1, -.2), upper = 1:3*.1, dif = c(F,T,F), row.names = paste("a", 1:3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
transform(dat, dif = lower > 0 | upper < 0)

#  lower upper   dif
#1 -0.41   0.1 FALSE
#2  0.10   0.2  TRUE
#3 -0.20   0.3 FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dplyr::between`:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dif = !between(0, lower, upper))
```

Output

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  lower upper dif  
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1 -0.41   0.1 FALSE
2  0.1    0.2 TRUE 
3 -0.2    0.3 FALSE
```

Comment: Ah! there is one problem, my actual data has rownames, applying your solution deletes the rownames!

Comment: It's true, tidyverse [doesn't like rownames as having a special status, distinct from columns](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html).  You can get around this by starting the chain with `dat %>% mutate(rn = row.names(.), .before = everything())`.  But unless you're committed to keeping everything in tidyverse, it's an unnecessary extra step in your case.

Comment: It is critically important to keep the rownames Andrew. I'm doing multiple comparison and the only thing that keep the user not get confused about the output is the rownames. Thank you, I'll upvote your solution though.

Comment: Understood - just calling out that rownames are really just another kind of column, and it's not hard to preserve them in that sense - especially for multiple comparisons.  Data frame indexes don't get the kind of privileged status they have in R as in, say, Python.  So the entire tidyverse framework encourages moving data into columnar format, including rownames/indexes.  But that's more a philosophical position than it is a practical one, imo, and as @Ronak Shah's solution gives a simple base R approach that preserves rownames, I think it's a great and better solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(dat, dif = lower > 0 | upper < 0)
```

---

Or an option in `base R`

```
Reduce(`|`, Map(function(x, y)  match.fun(y)(x, 0), dat, c(">", "<")))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: @rnorouzian Thank you. i showed a `Map` method in case you have multiple comparisons that are different for different columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `do.call` with `*`

```
dat$dif <- do.call("*", dat) > 0
```

such that

```
> dat
    lower upper   dif
a 1 -0.41   0.1 FALSE
a 2  0.10   0.2  TRUE
a 3 -0.20   0.3 FALSE
```